# Exception based on std::exception but easy to modify and rethrow

Tags: c++, c++11, exception-handling

I've looked at `boost::exception` and realized it is too advanced for my project, as my colleagues mostly have legacy C background. I do not need arbitrarily complex information in exception, just some error messages and trace info that can be written to process log.

Someone on Stack Overflow [wrote such code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481147/if-you-catch-an-exception-by-reference-can-you-modify-it-and-rethrow) as an example, but his solution can `throw` while trying to insert additional exception info (looks dangerous to me, correct me if I am wrong).

I tried to avoid using anything that can `throw` (vector of strings) inside the exception object. See: [usage example](http://ideone.com/a6Ope7).

Your feedback in term of correctness, ease of use, and required additional functionality is welcome.

```
const unsigned int long_enough = 512;
class my_exception : public exception {
    std::array<char, long_enough> err;
    std::array<char, long_enough>::iterator insertion_point;
public:
    template <typename Iter>
    void append(Iter first, Iter last) noexcept {
        //Remember null terminator!
        auto space_left = std::distance(insertion_point, err.end());
        if (std::distance(first, last)>=space_left){
            last = first + (space_left - 1);
        }
        insertion_point = copy(first, last, insertion_point);
    }
    void append(const char msg[]) noexcept {
        append(msg, msg+strlen(msg));
    }
    my_exception(const char msg[]) noexcept {
        insertion_point = err.begin();
        append(msg, msg+strlen(msg));
    }
    virtual const char* what() const noexcept override{
        return err.data();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

A note on the [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481147/if-you-catch-an-exception-by-reference-can-you-modify-it-and-rethrow) you posted; the OP was asking a hypothetical question in regards to what happens ('under the hood') to the call stack/exception/etc. if the exception that is caught is of a reference type (i.e. `catch (std::exception& e)` vs `catch (const std::exception& e)`). As was answered there, yes it is not a good idea to modify the exception within a catch (though completely legal code, still not advised).

Per your code, there are a couple of things worth noting:
changing your `err` type from a  `std::array<char, long_enough>` to a `std::string` would simplify all of your code, also, while you can pass a `const char[]` into functions, it decays into a pointer (pointing to the first element in the array), so it's similar to just `const char*`, if you're intent WAS to pass in a reference to a `char[]`, it's recommended you pass a const size, as in `template<int N> someFn(const char (&x)[N])`, otherwise stack issues can occur. As well, if you're working with C++, unless you have a specific need to use a `char[]` (which is possible) it's advised to use a `std::string` over a `char[]`.

Lastly, while having an `append` function to add aditional information into your exception object could be useful, it's usually better to derive a specific exception from your base exception with specific information in it (or otherwise just put the needed information in your `throw exception...`). Here's you're exception class with the `err` variable being a `std::string`

```
class my_exception : virtual public std::exception {
private:
    std::string err;
public:
    void append(std::string::iterator first, std::string::iterator last) {
        err.append(first, last);
    }
    void append(const char* msg) {
        err.append(msg);
    }
    my_exception(const char* msg) noexcept : err(msg) {}
    virtual const char* what() const throw() {
        return err.c_str();
    }
};
```

Use it like such:

```
try {
    throw my_exception("here's a simple message");
} catch (std::exception e) {
     e.append("...added some text");
     std::cout << "error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
     // or printf("error: %s\n", e.what()) for your C friends
}
```

As a side note (and for reference), here is the exception code from part of an open source framework I'm working on (just in a single header file exception.hpp):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <string>

namespace your_namespace {
    class exception : virtual public std::exception {
        public:
            exception() throw() : m_what("general exception") {}
            exception(const char *reason) throw() : m_what(reason) {}
            exception(const std::string& reason) throw() : m_what(reason) {}
            virtual ~exception() throw() {}
            virtual const char* what() const throw() { return m_what.c_str(); }
            virtual void seterr(const char *err) { this->m_what = std::string(err); }
            virtual void seterr(const std::string &err) { this->m_what = err; }
            friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, const omni::exception& e)
            { s << e.m_what; return s; }
            friend std::basic_ostream<wchar_t>& operator<<(std::basic_ostream<wchar_t>& s, const omni::exception& e) {
                s << e.m_what.c_str();
                return s;
            }
        protected:
            std::string m_what;
    };

    class some_other_exception : public your_namespace::exception {
        public:
            some_other_exception() : exception("some other exception happened") {}

    };
}
```

To use:

```
try {
    throw your_namespace::exception();
} catch (std::exception e) { // or const std::exception&
    std::cout << "error: " << e << std::endl;
    // or printf("error: %s\n", e.what()) for your C friends
}

try {
    throw your_namespace::exception("Here's an exception for you");
} catch (std::exception e) {
    std::cout << "error: " << e << std::endl;
}

try {
    throw your_namespace::some_other_exception();
} catch (std::exception e) {
    std::cout << "error: " << e << std::endl;
}
```

I hope that can help

Comment: @Deduplicator, I've edited my post to be a little more clear, I was more trying to point out that if they wanted to pass the reference itself instead of the decayed pointer (that is `char c[5]; someFn(&c)` vs `someFn(&c[0])`) then their syntax would need changing. I've witnessed some C++ devs who use `char[]` as a function parameter to intend something like the following: `someFn(char[]&)` without understanding that a `char[]` type gets decayed to a pointer type in a function call. So `someFn(char[])` and `someFn(char*)` are completely different types to these devs :/ Sorry for the confusion!